# How to measure power consumed by my algorithm?

Tags: linux, arm, cortex-a8

I have an image processing algorithm running on an **ARM-Cortex-A8/Ubuntu 9.01** platform and I have to measure the power consumed by my algorithm, does anyone know how to do this? Any tools available for this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73904/how-do-i-monitor-power-consumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking your algorithm doesn't consume power.

Presumably you have some hardware which can accurately measure the power usage of the device, so you should just be able to repeatedly run your code (on an otherwise idle device) on various test data sets and measure the cumulative power usage, and compare that with the idle power consumption of the device over the same time; the difference would be the amount of additional juice the device used running your code.

Like any kind of benchmark, you'll need to run it repeatedly in a loop to get accurate data.

As the data may change its performance characteristics, you'll need a corpus of different test data to simulate different use-cases. Talk to your QA team about it.

Comment: MarkR, do you know of any software tool which can monitor my processor power consumption over time? For example when I open the system Monitor application in Ubuntu, I see statistics of CPU, Memory and Network usage over time axis, it will be very useful to have such a tool. If not then I will find out if there are any external hardware .

Comment: I'm considering to use a digital Watt-meter to measure the power consumption of my board. I will attach it to the mains and connect my board to that and then I will do what you have suggested, take the reading in the idle state and then take the new reading when my algorithm is running. I just wish the watt-meter has a good resolution to measure even tiny changes.

Comment: What you really need to do is integrate it over time. You might be able to do this by putting a digital ameter on the DC feed to your development board and using some data acquisition software to integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think u can try POWERTOP and POWERSTAT and measure once while system is idle and once while running your program and difference might give you the necessary information.

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/powerstat-power-calculator-ubuntu-linux/

Thanks--

S Teja